# Two barnches connected to each other

Tags: git, branch

I had branch A, before I merged to master, I created new branch B.but I made a mistake, so branch B is connected to branch A. how I can separate these branches?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean my `separate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branches are not connected to each other. However, they may point to the same revision.

Given this, I think you mean that branch `B` pointed to a revision on branch `A`, when you wanted it to point to a revision on branch `master`.

To change this, you can remove the branch and then recreate it:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d b  # delete the old branch
git checkout -b  # create a new one based on current branch (master)
```

Be aware that this is risky if you have pushed the branch to a repo that others may have accessed. If you have only worked with your local repo, this is not an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it was my question exactly.it seems that it is not possible to keep branches. I have to delete them and create new ones.

Comment: You're very welcome! However, I don't know what you mean by "it is not possible to keep branches", unless you mean it in the way that I explained. I see you're new to StackOverflow; please read this about what to do when you get a satisfactory answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.